# How to restrict UITextField to take only numbers in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, uitextfield

I want the user to only enter numeric values in a `UITextField`. On iPhone we can show the numeric keyboard, but on iPad the user can switch to any keyboard.

Is there  any way to restrict user to enter only numeric values in a `UITextField`?

---

**Note:** This is an old question with many many answers. More than one third of the posted answers are wrong. Even some of the highly upvoted answers are wrong. Please, DO NOT post a new answer unless it somehow finds a vastly improved way to solve this question in a way that isn't shown already. Make sure your answer works in all circumstances. It must work for both iPhones and iPads. It must work when a user pastes text into the text field. It must work if the user has an external keyboard. It must work if the user changes the text selection in the text field before typing or pasting text. It must properly support decimal numbers (one decimal separator appropriate for the user's locale).

Comment: you have to alter the entered text.

Comment: yes , but in ipad user can enter alphabet even after if we set numeric keyboard

Comment: What do you mean by altering the text?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944789/allow-only-numbers-for-uitextfield-input/12944946#12944946

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26919854/how-can-i-declare-that-a-text-field-can-only-contain-an-integer

Answer (score 110):

#### Solution for swift 3.0 and above

```swift
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
    let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
    return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet)
}
```

Comment: Your view controller should conform `UITextFieldDelegate`, in viewDidLoad put `yourNumbersTextField.delegate = self`

Comment: what is range?.

Comment: why you didn't mention UITextFieldDelegate??

Comment: @user924 range is returned by UITextField delegate method

Comment: @user924 mention of UITextFieldDelegate is basic requirement

Answer (score 82):

Here is my 2 Cents. **(Tested on Swift 2 Only)**

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

  let aSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString:"0123456789").invertedSet
  let compSepByCharInSet = string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(aSet)
  let numberFiltered = compSepByCharInSet.joinWithSeparator("")
  return string == numberFiltered

}
```

This is just a little bit more strict. No decimal point either.

Hope it helps :)

PS: I assumed you looked after the delegate anyway.

**Update: Swift 3.0** :

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let aSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123456789").inverted
    let compSepByCharInSet = string.components(separatedBy: aSet)
    let numberFiltered = compSepByCharInSet.joined(separator: "")
    return string == numberFiltered
}
```

Comment: How would I restrict the UITextfield to only receive numbers and limit the amount of numbers between 6 and 8?

Comment: You can set `aSet` to just be `CharacterSet.decimalDigits.invertedSet`

Comment: Perfect for my needs. Thanks.

Comment: why you didn't mention UITextFieldDelegate??

Comment: You should also add a check for `text == ""` so the user can delete text backwards.

Answer (score 33):

In swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.4.1

Add **UITextFieldDelegate** to your class

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
```

Then write this code in your **viewDidLoad()**

```
mobileNoTF.delegate = self
```

Write this textfield delegate function

```
//MARK - UITextField Delegates
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    //For mobile numer validation
    if textField == mobileNoTF {
        let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn:"+0123456789 ")//Here change this characters based on your requirement
        let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
        return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet)
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: how do i fix `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UITextField' and '() -> ()'`

Comment: @iOS, how does it works? I've added everything, but I still can type anything. The field allows any characters and the textField function is not triggered.

Answer (score 16):

**iPhone**

In whatever UITextField you're getting these values from, you can specify the kind of keyboard you want to appear when somebody touches inside the text field.

E.G. a numeric-only keyboard.

Like this screenshot:

[image]

**iPad**

The iPad does not support the numeric keyboard, so your options are to either not support the iPad, validate the field post submit, or follow one of the other suggestions here to create same behaviors while running on an iPad.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Even when using the Number Pad, iOS would allow a user to paste non-numeric values into the UITextField or allow iPads to switch keyboards away from numeric.

Comment: This is simple answer of this question!! Not proper answer! I know!

Comment: It's not any answer to the question, neither simple nor proper. The question **isn't** asking for how to change the keyboard type. The question **is** asking how to restrict the input. Those are different.

Comment: Question is: How to restrict UITextField to take only numbers in Swift?
So when your keyboard type is number pad, obviously it's fulfill the requirements.

Comment: No, it doesn't, because the preferred keyboard type that you set on the UITextField is *not* the only way to enter text into a text field. As Rob said, you can also paste text into it, you can use an external keyboard, and some devices let you switch to a different keyboard type in any case.

Comment: The OP asks explicitly for another solution than changing keyboard type.

"On iPhone we can show the numeric keyboard, but on iPad the user can switch to any keyboard."

Comment: Actually this also doesn't answer for iPhone. If the user has a custom keyboard, you can bypass the numberPad only configuration.

Answer (score 14):

Swift 2.0

For only allowing numbers and one "." decimal in uitextfield.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField,shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    let newCharacters = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: string)
    let boolIsNumber = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().isSupersetOfSet(newCharacters)
    if boolIsNumber == true {
        return true
    } else {
        if string == "." {
            let countdots = textField.text!.componentsSeparatedByString(".").count - 1
            if countdots == 0 {
                return true
            } else {
                if countdots > 0 && string == "." {
                    return false
                } else {
                    return true
                }
            }
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that is great (i was looking for a solution to just allow 1 ".")

Answer (score 9):

Accept decimal values in text fields with single (.)dot in Swift 3

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let inverseSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123456789").inverted

    let components = string.components(separatedBy: inverseSet)

    let filtered = components.joined(separator: "")

    if filtered == string {
        return true
    } else {
        if string == "." {
            let countdots = textField.text!.components(separatedBy:".").count - 1
            if countdots == 0 {
                return true
            }else{
                if countdots > 0 && string == "." {
                    return false
                } else {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }else{
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only one (that restricts to one decimal) I could get working, awesome!

Comment: Actually I revised it to allow for one comma as well (as per FR)

Comment: Please note, that not all locales use the "." as a decimal separator.
You might want to use Locale.current.decimalSeparator instead.

Answer (score 7):

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // return true if the replacementString only contains numeric characters
    let digits = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()
    for c in string {
        if !digits.characterIsMember(c) {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

This solution will work even if the user switches keyboards or tries to paste a non-numeric string into the text field.

Make sure to set the `delegate` property of the appropriate text field.

Comment: Using `[string intValue]` as suggested in a previous answer will not work because that property could be true (non-zero) even if `string` contains non-numeric characters. According to the docs, `intValue` is 0 only if "the string doesn’t begin with a valid decimal text representation of a number."

Answer (score 7):

Extend your view controller like this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
```

In the viewDidLoad function extend to your text field like this:

```
myTextField.delegate = self
```

And then use the following function:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let isNumber = CharacterSet.decimalDigits.isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: string))
    let withDecimal = (
        string == NumberFormatter().decimalSeparator &&
        textField.text?.contains(string) == false
    )
    return isNumber || withDecimal
}
```

This will now make sure the user can enter only decimal digits.

Swift 4 +
Accepts Number only
and accepts one separator

Answer (score 5):

Use number formatter

**Swift 4.x**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
      let s = NSString(string: textField.text ?? "").replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
      guard !s.isEmpty else { return true }
      let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
      numberFormatter.numberStyle = .none
      return numberFormatter.number(from: s)?.intValue != nil
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! This one is better than many others because it allows decimal numbers but not arbitrary use of the decimal.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple solution, you need to connect the event "Editing changed" to this method in your controller

**Swift 4**

```
@IBAction func valueChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    if let last = sender.text?.last {
        let zero: Character = "0"
        let num: Int = Int(UnicodeScalar(String(last))!.value - UnicodeScalar(String(zero))!.value)
        if (num < 0 || num > 9) {
            //remove the last character as it is invalid
            sender.text?.removeLast()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A great solution if the delegate is already being consumed by Rx.

Comment: it will crash if i add space or symbols

Comment: This doesn't work if a user moves the caret or selects some text before typing. This code allows a user to paste in any arbitrary text as long as the last character is a number.

Answer (score 4):

> 1st you have to inherit the UITextFieldDelegate class with you own
>   class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

> 2nd add an IBOutlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!
```

> 3rd you have to assure this object is using

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   firstName.delegate = self
}


func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == firstName {
                let allowedCharacters = "1234567890"
                let allowedCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: allowedCharacters)
                let typedCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
                let alphabet = allowedCharacterSet.isSuperset(of: typedCharacterSet)
                return alphabet


      }
  }
```

Comment: Why would you name a text field for entering numbers as `firstName`? An outlet is not needed if the text field is created programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

Tested in swift 3.0

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool

{         
    let numberOnly = NSCharacterSet.init(charactersIn: "0123456789")
    let stringFromTextField = NSCharacterSet.init(charactersIn: string)
    let strValid = numberOnly.isSuperset(of: stringFromTextField as CharacterSet)

     return strValid
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

While most of these solutions will work, be aware that in some localisations a decimals are separated with a "," and not a "."

The cleaner way to do this would be

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let decimalCharacter = NSNumberFormatter().decimalSeparator
    let characterSet = NSMutableCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()
    characterSet.addCharactersInString(decimalCharacter)

    return replacementString.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(characterSet.invertedSet) == nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had actually done this when working through the Big Nerd Ranch book, my solution is:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, 
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, 
    replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let newCharacters = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: string)
    return NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().isSupersetOfSet(newCharacters)
}
```

this only allows the numbers 0-9, to allow the "." as well is more complicated as you can only allow one "."

Answer (score 2):

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if let numRange = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet()) {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

To allow only numbers and just one decimal operator, you can use this solution:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let isNumber = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().isSupersetOfSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: string))

    return isNumber || (string == NSNumberFormatter().decimalSeparator && textField.text?.containsString(string) == false)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool

        {
            let textString = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

            if textField == self.phoneTextField  && string.characters.count > 0{
                let numberOnly = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits
                let strValid = numberOnly.contains(UnicodeScalar.init(string)!)
                return strValid && textString.characters.count <= 10
            }
            return true
        }
```

in above code is working in swift 3 
NSCharacterSet.**decimalDigits**
You are also use letters only 
NSCharacterSet.**Letters**
and **uppercase,Lowercaseand,alphanumerics,whitespaces**
is used same code
 or  [See the Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31480558/uitextfield-keyboard-with-only-alphabet-no-numbers-no-caps-no-spacebar/44449799#44449799)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an cleaner solution:

```
 guard CharacterSet(charactersIn: "123456789").isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)) else {
     return false
 }
 return true
```

For decimals just add `.`, example `123456789.`

Comment: It's little bit nice, but compare to this use UITextfiled delegate.

Comment: For decimals this would allow a user to enter more than one decimal.

Answer (score 2):

Set KeyboardType  Property :- Number Pad 
TextField Delegate please write below code

```
  func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn 
  range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if textField.text?.count == 0 && string == "0" {
        return false
    }
    return string == string.filter("0123456789".contains)
}
```

Number should not start from 0  and entered number +ve.

Comment: Never rely on the keyboard type. A user can still paste in arbitrary text or an external keyboard could be used. And please read the question about the iPad. Why does this answer prevent a user from entering a `0` into an empty text field?

Answer (score 2):

//instead of these you can simply change your keyboard to number type

```
yourtextfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
```

Comment: This cannot resolve this problem, as the user can paste non-numeric characters into the text field.

Comment: then you can use number extension

Answer (score 1):

```
Swift 2.0

func textField(textField: UITextField,
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
    replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let inverseSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString:"0123456789").invertedSet

        let components = string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(inverseSet)

        let filtered = components.joinWithSeparator("")

        return string == filtered

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As if there aren't enough answers, here's mine. I think every example allowed for decimal separators is flawed in either localization, backspaces, or copy/paste.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if string.isEmpty {return true} //allow for backspace

    let decimalSeparator = NSNumberFormatter().decimalSeparator ?? "."
    let validChars = NSMutableCharacterSet(charactersInString: decimalSeparator)
    validChars.formUnionWithCharacterSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet())

    if validChars.isSupersetOfSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: string)){
        switch string.componentsSeparatedByString(decimalSeparator).count-1 {
        case 0: //no decimals
            return true

        case 1: //if adding decimal, only allow if no existing decimal
            if let existingText = textField.text{
                return existingText.componentsSeparatedByString(decimalSeparator).count <= 1
            }
            else {return true}

        default: //invalid decimals
            return false
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func isValidNumber(str:String) -> Bool{
    if str.isEmpty {
        return false
    }
    let newChar = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: str)
    let boolValid = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().isSupersetOfSet(newChar)
    if boolValid{
        return true
    }else{
        let lst = str.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
        let newStr = lst.joinWithSeparator("")
        let currentChar = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: newStr)
        if lst.count == 2 && !lst.contains("") && NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().isSupersetOfSet(currentChar){
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Put this function in your "Submit" or "Save" method if there is one.

Comment: this is great!  updated for Swift 5.0

Answer (score 1):

The following is the code I used in Swift 3.0 adapted from Mr H's code. Differences are because:

a) Delegate function declaration has changed in Swift 3.0. [New declaration here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield)

b) NSCharacterSet declaration has changed.

```
func textField(_ shouldChangeCharactersIntextField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{

        let inverseSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123456789").inverted

        let components = string.components(separatedBy: inverseSet)

        let filtered = components.joined(separator: "")

        return string == filtered

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have edited Raj Joshi's version to allow one dot or one comma:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let inverseSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123456789").inverted
    let components = string.components(separatedBy: inverseSet)
    let filtered = components.joined(separator: "")

    if filtered == string {
        return true
    } else {
        if string == "." || string == "," {
            let countDots = textField.text!.components(separatedBy:".").count - 1
            let countCommas = textField.text!.components(separatedBy:",").count - 1

            if countDots == 0 && countCommas == 0 {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        } else  {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This fails under some conditions. This doesn't take into account the possibility of the user selecting some text before typing or pasting text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code if you want to allow decimal separator and/or negative numbers.
But this code allows example: "34." (decimal separator at the end) while changing text. So you have to add some code example: textFieldShouldReturn or textFieldShouldEndEditing delegate functions.

The code written in Swift 4 but I assueme this is compatible with Swift 3.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let text = textField.text else {
        return true
    }

    let replaced = (text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    let decimalSeparator = NSLocale.current.decimalSeparator ?? ""

    // When user wants to delete las character
    if replaced == "" || replaced == "-" || replaced == "-0" {
        textField.text = "0"
        return false
    }

    // When text contains 0 before replace except "0."
    if replaced != "0" + decimalSeparator && replaced.hasPrefix("0") && text.underestimatedCount == 1 {
        textField.text = replaced.substring(from: replaced.index(after: replaced.startIndex))
        return false
    }

    // When user wants to delete minus sign
    if text.hasPrefix("-") && text.substring(from: text.index(after: text.startIndex)) == replaced {
        return false
    }

    // When user wants to delete before decimal separator
    if replaced.hasPrefix(decimalSeparator) || replaced.hasPrefix("-" + decimalSeparator) {
        return false
    }

    // When user wants to add zero the beginning of number... but allowing "0." or "-0." numbers
    let testReplaced = replaced.hasPrefix("-") ? replaced.substring(from: replaced.index(after: replaced.startIndex)) : replaced
    if testReplaced.count >= 2 && testReplaced.hasPrefix("0") && !testReplaced.hasPrefix("0" + decimalSeparator) {
        return false
    }

    // Every other cases
    let allowDecimal = self.allowFloat ? (decimalSeparator == "." ? "\\.?" : decimalSeparator + "?") : ""
    let allowSign = self.allowSigned ? "-?" : ""
    let pattern = "\(allowSign)[0-9]+\(allowDecimal)([0-9]+)?"

    do {
        let regexRange = (replaced as NSString).range(of: replaced)
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
        let matches = regex.matches(in: replaced, options: [], range: regexRange)
        return matches.count == 1 && matches.first!.range == regexRange
    }
    catch {}

    return false
}
```

If you don't want to allow decimal or negative numbers you have to replace tow variable with next line

```
let allowDecimal = ""
let allowSign = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

For allow some charactors

```
func CheckAddress(string:String) -> Bool  {
        let numberOnly = NSCharacterSet.init(charactersIn: "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-@,&#/")
        let stringFromTextField = NSCharacterSet.init(charactersIn: string)
        return numberOnly.isSuperset(of: stringFromTextField as CharacterSet)
    }

print("\(CheckAddress(string: "123"))") //True
print("\(CheckAddress(string: "asdf-"))") //True
print("\(CheckAddress(string: "asd123$"))") //false
```

Comment: The question is asking about entering numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more readable version that will do "0-9" plus ".":

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let existingTextHasDecimal = textField.text?.rangeOfString(".")
    let replacementTextHasDecimal = string.rangeOfString(".")
    let replacementTextAllCharacters = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: string)
    let replacementTextOnlyDigits = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().isSupersetOfSet(replacementTextAllCharacters)

    if replacementTextHasDecimal != nil && existingTextHasDecimal != nil {
        return false
    }else{
        if replacementTextOnlyDigits == true {
            return true
        }else if replacementTextHasDecimal != nil{
            return true
        }else{
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This fails in many instances. This doesn't take into account the user selecting some existing text before typing or pasting in new text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shouldChangeCharactersInRange along with String extension method to check if the input string is number or not.

```
extension String  {

    var isNumber : Bool {
        get{
            return !self.isEmpty && self.stringWithoutWhitespaces.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted) == nil
        }
    }

    var stringWithoutWhitespaces: String {
        return self.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    }

}

//Mark: shouldChangeCharactersInRange
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // return true if the string only contains numeric characters
    let isValid = string.stringWithoutWhitespaces.isNumber 
    return valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dead simple solution for `Double` numbers (keep it mind that this is not the best user-friendly solution), in your `UITextFieldDelegate` delegate:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
               shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
               replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        guard let currentString = textField.text as NSString? else {
            return false
        }
        let newString = currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        return Double(newString) != nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach that solves both decimal and Int:

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let currentText = textField.text
    let futureString = currentText.substring(toIndex: range.location) + string + currentText.substring(fromIndex: range.location + range.length)
    
    if futureString.count == 0 {
        return true
    }
    
    if isDecimal {
        if let numberAsDouble = Double(futureString), numberAsDouble.asPrice.count >= futureString.count {
            return true
        }
    } else if let numberAsInt = Int(futureString), "\(numberAsInt)".count == futureString.count {
        return true
    }
    
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When copying and pasting, there is a possibility of accidentally entering duplicate decimal points in numeric values. The following solution ensures that only numeric values and a single decimal point are allowed.

```
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let allowedCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.")
        let replacementStringCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
        let isNumeric = allowedCharacterSet.isSuperset(of: replacementStringCharacterSet)
        
        if !isNumeric {
            return false
        }
        
        let currentText = textField.text ?? ""
        
        if string.contains(".") {
            // Check if the text already contains a dot
            let containsDot = currentText.contains(".")
            if containsDot {
                return false
            }
        }
        
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

//Only accept decimal numbers as input, [ SWIFT 3.0 ]

```
func textField(_ shouldChangeCharactersIntextField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
        let inverseSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123456789").inverted

        let components = string.components(separatedBy: inverseSet)

        let filtered = components.joined(separator: "")

        return string == filtered
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift 3

```
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField==yourTextFieldOutlet {
                if(CharacterSet.decimalDigits.isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: yourTextFieldOutlet.text!))){
//if numbers only, then your code here
                }
                else{
                showAlert(title: "Error",message: "Enter Number only",type: "failure")
                }
            }
    return true
    }
```

Comment: This only checks the previous value of the text field. This makes no attempt to validate the newly changed text.

Answer (score -2):

First add `delegate` and `keyBoradType` of `textField`

`textField.delegate=self;
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;`

Than have to use the `textField.delegate` method like so -

```
- (BOOL) textField: (UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString: (NSString *)string 
{
  if (!string.length)
  {
       return YES;
  }

  if ([string intValue])
  {
        return YES;
  }

  return NO;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Updated Cian's response above to Swift 3:

`func textField(textField: UITextField,shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    let newCharacters = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
    let boolIsNumber = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits.isSuperset(of:newCharacters as CharacterSet)
    if boolIsNumber == true {
        return true
    } else {
        if string == "." {
            let countdots = textField.text!.components(separatedBy:".").count - 1
            if countdots == 0 {
                return true
            } else {
                if countdots > 0 && string == "." {
                    return false
                } else {
                    return true
                }
            }
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}`

Comment: This could be lot better. you could use Characterset instead of NSCHaracterset. Not a proper conversion

Answer (score -2):

In case someone wants only "English" letters or numbers, there is ACCII Capable option in the Keyboard type list in the Attributes Inspector
[image]