# Entering Date in dd-MM-yyyy format using numeric keyboard in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, date-formatting

I want to format (dd-MM-yyyy) the text while entering in UITextField. I am using Swift 3.0, Any suggestion how I can implement the same.

Comment: I will suggest, create a Date picker which displays date in your desired format and put that picker view as a Input-view of that textfield.

Comment: I didn't tried anything till now, I have no clue how to implement

Comment: Design requirement is to implement that with a keyboard not a picker, Date picker is already working

Comment: down voter please provide comment.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use like

```
// create one textfield
@IBOutlet var txtDOB: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // set delegate for your textfield
    txtDOB.delegate = self

}
```

// call your function in `textfield` delegate `shouldChangeCharactersIn`

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    //Format Date of Birth dd-MM-yyyy

    //initially identify your textfield

    if textField == txtDOB {

        // check the chars length dd -->2 at the same time calculate the dd-MM --> 5
        if (txtDOB?.text?.characters.count == 2) || (txtDOB?.text?.characters.count == 5) {
            //Handle backspace being pressed
            if !(string == "") {
                // append the text
                txtDOB?.text = (txtDOB?.text)! + "-"
            }
        }
        // check the condition not exceed 9 chars
        return !(textField.text!.characters.count > 9 && (string.characters.count ) > range.length)
    }
    else {
        return true
    }
}
```

**ObjectiveC**

```
  - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
  {
//Format Date of Birth dd-MM-yyyy

 if(textField == txtDOB)
    {
    if ((txtDOB.text.length == 2)||(txtDOB.text.length == 5))
        //Handle backspace being pressed
        if (![string isEqualToString:@""])
            txtDOB.text = [txtDOB.text stringByAppendingString:@"-"];
    return !([textField.text length]>9 && [string length] > range.length);
}
else
    return YES;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Anbu.Karthik, Its working as per requirement, one minor question if you can help. I want only numeric characters, number keyboard have decimal point too. how can I avoid that ?

Comment: @Haroon - see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30973044/how-to-restrict-uitextfield-to-take-only-numbers-in-swift

Answer (score 4):

Updated for Swift 5

```
if textField == dateTextField {
            if dateTextField.text?.count == 2 || dateTextField.text?.count == 5 {
                //Handle backspace being pressed
                if !(string == "") {
                    // append the text
                    dateTextField.text = dateTextField.text! + "."
                }
            }
            // check the condition not exceed 9 chars
            return !(textField.text!.count > 9 && (string.count ) > range.length)
        } else {
            return true
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **SwiftUI** solution.

```
struct DobScreen: View {
@State private var dobText: String = ""
@State var textLen = 0

var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            TextField("MM-DD-YYYY", text: $dobText)
            .onChange(of: dobText) { newValue in
                
                if newValue.count < textLen {
                    // If the length of the new value is less than the previous length,
                    // it indicates a deletion (backspace).
                    dobText = ""
                    textLen = 0
                    return
                }
                // Check if the input length exceeds 10 characters
                 guard newValue.count <= 10 else {
                     dobText = String(newValue.prefix(10))
                     return
                 }
                
                 // Handle backspace
                 if newValue.count < dobText.count {
                     // If the length of the new value is less than the previous length,
                     // it indicates a deletion (backspace).
                     dobText = ""
                     return
                 }
                 
                 // Add separators for MM / DD / YYYY format
                 if newValue.count >= 2 && !newValue.contains("-") {
                     dobText.insert("-", at: dobText.index(dobText.startIndex, offsetBy: 2))
                 }
                 if newValue.count >= 5 && !newValue[dobText.index(dobText.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)...].contains("-") {
                     dobText.insert("-", at: dobText.index(dobText.startIndex, offsetBy: 5))
                 }
                textLen = dobText.count
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```