# Assigning text field value to variable in Swift

Tags: swift, forced-unwrapping

I am trying to learn Swift and it is turning out to be more different from other languages than I expected...

I just want to store the value of a user's input as an integer in a variable.

My attempts result in the following error:
"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

I have tried this multiple ways and can't seem to come up with a solution, I know there must a simple way to do this.

```
var intNumber: Int = 0
@IBOutlet weak var txt_Number: UITextField!

for view in self.view.subviews as [UIView]{
if let txt = view as? UITextField
{
    if let txtData = txt.text where txtData.isEmpty
    {
        // Error Message
    }
    else
    {
        intNumber = Int(txt_Number.text)
    }
}
}
```

I know the above code isn't correct, but I think that's the closest to correct I have come. I seem to be missing something as far as unwrapping goes. I understand the principal of unwrapping, but nothing I have tried will compile, or if it does compile then it fails with the error above when the code is initiated (code is initiated when a button is pressed).

Thank you in advanced for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Make sure your outlet is hooked up to `txt_Number`. All of that code checking to make sure it's not `nil` is not necessary if (a) it's an outlet you hooked up in IB; and (b) you're not doing the above code before the view is completely loaded (i.e. `viewDidLoad` was called).

   If the outlet is not hooked up, you'll see an empty dot on the left margin:

   [image]

   If it is hooked up correctly, you'll see a filled in dot on the left margin:

   [image]
2. If everything is  hooked up correctly, you can just do:

   ```
   guard let txtData = txt_Number.text, let value = Int(txtData) else {
       // report error and then `return`
       return
   }

   intNumber = value
   ```
3. If you want to get fancy, you might want to ensure the user only enters numeric values by

   - In `viewDidLoad`, specify that the keyboard is for decimal numbers only.

     ```
     txt_Number.keyboardType = .NumberPad
     ```

     Or you can specify this in IB, too.
   - Specify a delegate for the text field and only allow them to enter numeric values. (This might seem redundant based upon the prior point, but it's not, because you have to also anticipate them pasting in a string to the text field.)

   See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26940387/1271826.

Comment: Better to tell him to use `intNumber = Int(txtData) ?? 0` so we can prevent a question being asked about optional error :).

Comment: @Eendje - Agree. Or use a `guard` statement that assigns the value accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you don't have to iterate over `subviews` if you have direct reference `txt_Number`, but this is not an essence of your question.

`if let` semantics will let you unwrap any optional inside `{}` brackets, so the most visible solution here is to:

```
if let unwrappedString = txt_Number.text {
    if let unwrappedIntegerInit = Int(unwrappedString) {
        intNumber = unwrappedIntegerInit
    }
}
```

My full example from playgrounds:

```
var intNumber: Int = 0
var txt_Number: UITextField = UITextField()
txt_Number.text = "12"

if let unwrappedString = txt_Number.text {
    if let unwrappedIntegerInit = Int(unwrappedString) {
        intNumber = unwrappedIntegerInit
    }
}

print(intNumber)
```

Or you can use guard inside a function:

```
func parse() {
    guard let text = txt_Number.text, let number = Int(text) else { return } // no text
    intNumber = number
}
```

**TIP:**
You have to unwrap `txt_Number.text` and `Int(text)` separately cause `Int(text)` has to have nonoptional argument.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with this?

```
if let txtData = txt.text where !txtData.isEmpty
{
    intNumber = Int(txtData)
}
else
{
    // Error Message
}
```

**ADD**:

`Int()` function returns an `Optional`. If you are sure that the value is correct, you can force the unwrapping by using `!` at the end of the variable name (when you are using it), otherwise just put the question mark `?`

Comment: I did, I get the following error: Value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Comment: `Int()` function returns an `Optional`. If you are sure that the value is correct, you can force the unwrapping by using `!` at the end of the variable name (when you are using it), otherwise just put the question mark `?`

Answer (score 0):

tried below code to assign value of TextField to variable of float type and all bug disappear like magic

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtamount: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtrate: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtyear: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var lblresult: UILabel!
@IBAction func btncalculate(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    print("button is clicked")
    var amount,rate,year,answer : Float

    amount = Float(txtamount.text!)!
    rate = Float(txtrate.text!)!
    year = Float(txtyear.text!)!

    answer = (amount * rate * year) / 100.0
}
```