# the button is disabled when text view is empty else is enabled

Tags: swift, ios9

I'm developing note app, when the text view is empty the done button should be disabled so user could not be able to save empty notes into data base, else the button should be enabled.

here's my code below, my attempts have failed; how I can solve this problem?

```
 @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
 @IBOutlet weak var done: UIBarButtonItem!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = note?.text
        if (self.textView.text.isEmpty){
            done.enabled = false
        }
        if let noteContent = note

        {
            textView.text = noteContent.text
        }

         self.navigationController!.toolbarHidden = false;
    }

  func textViewShouldBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) -> Bool{
done.enabled = true

    return done.enabled
}
```

Comment: "my attempts have failed" Where are they? I don't see you responding to changes in the text at all.

Comment: @matt look into code above, in `viewDidLoad` function if the textview is empty than disable button, and in  `textViewShouldBeginEditing` function enable done button if text view is not empty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make your view controller conform to `UITextViewDelegate` protocol
2. In Interface Builder, connect the `delegate` on the text view to your view controller.
3. Add the following function to your view controller:

---

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView == self.textView {
        self.doneButton.enabled = !textView.text.isEmpty
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another delegate method for you're purpose. This is example :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textView.delegate = self

        if (textView.text.isEmpty) {
            button.enabled = false
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {

    func textView(textView: UITextView, range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool
    {
        if (!textView.text.isEmpty) {
            button.enabled = true
        } else {
             button.enabled = false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: try to learn a bit about UITextViewDelegate this code is working right now in my project

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `textViewDidChange` method:

```
yourBarButtonItem.isEnabled = !(yourTextField.text?.isEmpty ?? false)
```